# Display Box A or Box B if then condition

Tags: conditionals, datatool, ifthenelse

I am using `datatool` and want to display `\posterbox` A, hide box B if `\TextA` = value, if `\TextA` = blank display `\posterbox` B and hide box A.

Box A & Box B are different: Image, item, color, position of image, number of items...

My Minimal Coding:

```
      \RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
 No,TextA,TextB
 1,a1,b1
 2,a2,b2
 3,,b3
 4,,
 5,a5,b5
 6,,b6

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
 \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}


 \DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}

 \begin{document}

 \DTLforeach*
 {file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextA=TextA,\TextB=TextB}
 {%
 \begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=1,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]
%Box A
\posterbox[colframe=red,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=A,column=1}{
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a} 
 \begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin =-1em, rightmargin=-1em]
\item \TextA
\end{enumerate}

}
%\newpage
\hspace{7cm}
%Box B
\posterbox[colframe=blue,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=B,column=1}{
 \begin{enumerate}

\item \TextB
\item \TextB
\item \TextB
\end{enumerate}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This code will exclude box A if `\TextA` is empty, and it will exclude Box B is `\TextA` is not empty.  Still waiting for guidance on what to do if both `\TextA` and `\TextB` are empty.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
 No,TextA,TextB
 1,a1,b1
 2,a2,b2
 3,,b3
 4,,
 5,a5,b5
 6,,b6

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
 \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}


 \DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}

 \begin{document}

 \DTLforeach*
 {file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextA=TextA,\TextB=TextB}
 {%
 \begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=1,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]
%Box A
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\TextA\relax\else
\posterbox[colframe=red,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=A,column=1}{
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a} 
 \begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin =-1em, rightmargin=-1em]
\item \TextA
\end{enumerate}
}\fi
%\newpage
\hspace{7cm}
%Box B
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\TextA\relax
\posterbox[colframe=blue,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=B,column=1}{
 \begin{enumerate}

\item \TextB
\item \TextB
\item \TextB
\end{enumerate}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
}\fi
\end{tcbposter}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is really good and can you edit: now a1, a5 can see both box A & Box B. I need if a1, a5 !=blank then see only box A, and don't display box B. 2/ And "%% EXCLUDE BOX B IF \TextA = a2": can you correcht \TextA !=blank => Excude box B. Please compare with blank, not "a2". I don;t understand it. Thanks

Comment: @latexforti Do I understand that if **ever** `\TextA` is non-empty, that you would like only Box A and not Box B?

Comment: @latexforti  ...and what if neither `\TextA` nor `\TextB` are defined?  What then?

Comment: B.Segletes. Your code is awesome, it works. If both (\TextA &\Text B = blank) then i will edit input in table. Manythanks