# if then, expandafter condition with 2 parameters - show and hide boxes

Tags: conditionals

In topic: [Display Box A or Box B if then condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489744/display-box-a-or-box-b-if-then-condition/489817#489817)

i have used only one paratemeter

Old Rule: condition with TextX

```
\TextX      |            Show             |         Hide

Value      |     \posterbox A            |          \posterbox B

Blank       |    \posterbox B              |         \posterbox A
```

Now I want to create New Rule: condition with 2 parameters: TextX, TextY

```
\TextX     |   \TextY     |  Show one box       |                 Hide 3 boxes

Value      |   Value      |  \posterbox A     |                    B,C,D

Value      |   Blank     |   \posterbox B            |             A,C,D

Blank     |    Value     |   \posterbox C         |                A,B,D

Blank     |    Blank     |   \posterbox D         |                A,B,C
```

Minimal working code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
 No,TextX,TextY,TextZ,TextW
 1,x1,y1,z1,w1
 2,,y2,z2,w2
 3,,y3,w3,
 4,,,,w4
 5,x5,y5,,
 6,,y6,z6,w6
 7,x7,y7,z7,w7

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
 \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}


 \DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}

 \begin{document}

 \DTLforeach*
 {file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextX=TextX,\TextY=TextY,\TextZ=TextZ,\TexW=TextW}
 {%
 \begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=1,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]
%Box A
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\TextX\relax\else
\posterbox[colframe=red,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=A,column=1}{
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a} 
 \begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin =-1em, rightmargin=-1em]
\item A \TextX
\end{enumerate}
}\fi
%\newpage

%Box B
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\TextX\relax
\posterbox[colframe=blue,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=B,column=1,xshift=5.0cm,yshift=0.0cm}{
 \begin{enumerate}

\item B \TextY
\item B \TextY
\item B \TextY
\end{enumerate}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
}\fi
\vspace{2cm}
%BoxC
\posterbox[colframe=green,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=C,column=1,xshift=1.0cm,yshift=-7.0cm}{
\begin{enumerate}

\item C \TextZ
\item C \TextZ
\end{enumerate}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-c}
}
%BoxD
\posterbox[colframe=black,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=C,column=1,xshift=8.0cm,yshift=-7.0cm}{
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}
 \begin{enumerate}

\item D \TextW
\item D \TextW
\end{enumerate}

}
\end{tcbposter}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Please update code with new rule: 2 paramters

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest some `\if` conditionals:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
 No,TextX,TextY,TextZ,TextW
 1,x1,y1,z1,w1
 2,,y2,z2,w2
 3,,y3,w3,
 4,,,,w4
 5,x5,y5,,
 6,,y6,z6,w6
 7,x7,y7,z7,w7
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
\tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}

\DTLloaddb{file}{\jobname.dat}

\newcommand{\select}[2]{%
  \if\relax#1\relax
    \if\relax#2\relax
      \selectD % 00
    \else
      \selectC % 01
    \fi
  \else
    \if\relax#2\relax
      \selectB % 10
    \else
      \selectA % 11
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\selectA}{%
  \posterbox[colframe=red,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=A,column=1}{%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a} 
    \begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin =-1em, rightmargin=-1em]
    \item A \TextX
    \end{enumerate}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\selectB}{%
  %Box B
  \posterbox[colframe=blue,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=B,column=1,xshift=5.0cm,yshift=0.0cm}{%
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item B \TextY
    \item B \TextY
    \item B \TextY
  \end{enumerate}
  \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\selectC}{%
  %BoxC
  \posterbox[colframe=green,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=C,column=1,xshift=1.0cm,yshift=-7.0cm}{%
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item C \TextZ
    \item C \TextZ
    \end{enumerate}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-c}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\selectD}{%
  %BoxD
  \posterbox[colframe=black,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=C,column=1,xshift=8.0cm,yshift=-7.0cm}{%
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item D \TextW
    \item D \TextW
    \end{enumerate}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextX=TextX,\TextY=TextY,\TextZ=TextZ,\TextW=TextW}
 {%
  \begin{tcbposter}[
    poster = {
      columns=1,
      rows=1,
      spacing=3mm,
      height=14cm,
      width=12cm,
    },
  ]
  \select{\TextX}{\TextY}
  \end{tcbposter}
  \newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could extend the idea from your previous post and do this by having multiple branches of `\if`-statements like

```
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\TextX\relax
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\TextY\relax\else
  ...
\fi\fi...\fi
```

but this will end up looking pretty nasty. Instead, the code below defines a command `\FourWayChoice` that accepts `6` arguments and is used as

```
\FourWayChoice{\TextX}{\TextY}{Box A}{Box B}{Box C}{Box D}
```

where the different "boxes" are chosen as per the table in the OP. The definition of the `\FourWayChoice` macro is pretty easy, partly because I use [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exlp). You can use the same idea to answer the previous post.

Using this code, page 2 of the MWE looks like this:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
 No,TextX,TextY,TextZ,TextW
 1,x1,y1,z1,w1
 2,,y2,z2,w2
 3,,y3,w3,
 4,,,,w4
 5,x5,y5,,
 6,,y6,z6,w6
 7,x7,y7,z7,w7

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
\tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}
\DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn {No}
\str_new:N \l_text_x_str
\str_new:N \l_text_y_str
\NewDocumentCommand\FourWayChoice{ mm mmmm }{
  \str_set:No \l_text_x_str {#1}
  \str_set:No \l_text_y_str {#2}
  \str_if_empty:NTF \l_text_x_str
    { \str_if_empty:NTF \l_text_y_str {#6} {#5} }
    { \str_if_empty:NTF \l_text_y_str {#4} {#3} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

 \DTLforeach*
 {file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextX=TextX,\TextY=TextY,\TextZ=TextZ,\TextW=TextW}
 {%
 \begin{tcbposter}[
    poster = {
      columns=1,
      rows=1,
      spacing=3mm,
      height=14cm,
      width=12cm,
    },
  ]
  \FourWayChoice{\TextX}{\TextY}
    { % Box A
      \posterbox[colframe=red,width=5cm,height=5cm]{name=A,column=1}{
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
          \begin{enumerate}[wide, leftmargin =-1em, rightmargin=-1em]
             \item A \TextX
          \end{enumerate}
        }
    }
    { % Box B
      \posterbox[colframe=blue,width=5cm,height=5cm]
        {name=B,column=1,xshift=5.0cm,yshift=0.0cm}{
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item B \TextY
          \item B \TextY
          \item B \TextY
        \end{enumerate}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
      }
    }
    { % BoxC
      \posterbox[colframe=green,width=5cm,height=5cm]
         {name=C,column=1,xshift=1.0cm,yshift=-7.0cm}{
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item C \TextZ
          \item C \TextZ
        \end{enumerate}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-c}
      }
    }
    { % BoxD
      \posterbox[colframe=black,width=5cm,height=5cm]
        {name=C,column=1,xshift=8.0cm,yshift=-7.0cm}{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item D \TextW
          \item D \TextW
        \end{enumerate}
      }
    }
  \end{tcbposter}
  %\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i use your above code but there are 4 pages. Other pages: 2,4,6 do not display?

Comment: @latexforti Note that I commented out the `\newpage` at the bottom. If I remove then comment then this generates 7 pages for me,  as it should since `file.tex` has 7 entries.